# Python to JavaScript object graph (de)serialization

Tags: javascript, python, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to send an object graph from Python to JavaScript running in a browser, and I was wondering whether there is a pair of ready-to-use libraries for handling serialization on the Python side and deserialization on the JavaScript side. JSON does not support object references out of the box, the docs for JS-YAML say it's not production-ready in a browser environment, and I didn't find anything for XML. Any suggestions?

**edit:** Here's an example for what I mean by "JSON does not support object references out of the box": I have a shop database with products and orders and a many-to-many relationship between them. If I put a bunch of orders into the Python JSON serializer, the result will contain multiple serializations (copies) of each product, because the JSON serializer has no way of saying, "I've serialized this product already, so I'll just insert a reference to it". So I put the result on the wire and deserialize it on the client, and now I have multiple JavaScript objects representing the same product, which is bad.

Comment: I use JSON for this, but I'd love a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

how about jsonpickle? JS is awesome with json out of box, adding json pickling in python is the missing link:
[jsonpickle](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpickle/)

Comment: Indeed, jsonpickle would be half of the solution, but there's no counterpart on the JS side that would reconstruct 'classes' (call an appropritate constructor function, clone the right objects etc.)

Comment: What do you mean? JS has the JSON library built in var myClass = JSON.parse('this is a json string') or backwards var myJSONtxt = JSON.stringify(myClass), is that what you're looking for?